# express 3.0.0 views not rendering

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using the book "Smashing Node.js" by Guillermo Rauch. Chap. 12 sets up some views/routes before an authentication example. I have followed the tutorial to the best of my ability and searched (and searched) for my error.

```
//package.json
{
"name": "login"
,"version":"0.0.1"
,"main":"./index"
,"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.0"
    ,"uglify-js" : "2.4.0"
    ,"mongodb":"1.3.19"
    ,"mongoose":"3.6.20"
    ,"bcrypt":"0.7.7"
    ,"jade":"0.35.0"
}
}
```

here is my index.js

```
/**module dependenies**/
var     express =   require('express')
        ,   mongodb =   require('mongodb');

//set up app

app = express();

//middleware
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'my secret'}));

//view options

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

//app.set('view options', {layout: false});

//routes

//default route
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    console.log('default');
    res.render('index', {authenticated: false});

});

//login route
app.get('/login', function (req, res){
    console.log('login');
    res.render('login');

});

//signup route
app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    console.log('signup');
    res.render('signup');

});

//listen

app.listen(3000);
```

in the same directory I have a folder of views/layout.jade, index.jade, signup.jade, login.jade I will show two.
'layout.jade'

```
doctype 5
html
    head


        title BN Login
    body
        .wrapper
        block body
```

and index.jade

```
extends layout
block body
if (authenticated)
    p   Welcome back, #{me.first}
    a(href="/logout") Logout
else
    p Welcome visitor!
    ul
        li: a(href='/login') Login 
        li: a(href="/signup") Signup
```

the lines I have commented out did not help or are old.

The layout.jade renders. The console shows that the code is being read. No other view is rendered.

Thanks.

Comment: the layout.jade is turned into html and rendered by the browser but it is not extended by index, signup, or login. No errors are logged. the message I added to the routes is logged to the console when I visit the corresponding url. I can add text to layout but otherwise the page and the browser console are blank (of course you can view the source and see the html).here it is on git:https://github.com/Ebot79/expressTest.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not used indentation correctly. In your index this :

```
extends layout
block body
if (authenticated)
...
else
```

should be :

```
extends layout
block body
  if (authenticated)
  ...
  else
```

Comment: @EricSheasby You can accept the answer, to show the question has been solved.

Comment: is there a link or something? I clicked the check mark within an hour of your post.

Comment: I checked the book again. The code is wrong. No problem thanks to @user568109. The book is 'Smashing Nodejs; JavaScript Everywhere" from Wiley publishers copyright 2012.